# checkbox que cuando clickeada convierte complete a true

Tags: javascript

soy nueva en esto y estoy tratando de crear una checkbox que cuendo sea clickeada, haga que la variable complete sea true en local storage. Aplique un event listener a la checkbox que advierte que checkbox y complete son iguales. Tambien he tratado de hacerlo con un onclick en el HTML llamando a la funcon (pero no funciona). Apreciaria mucho su ayuda. Gracias

```
`<li id='chore${i}'class='chore'>
    <div class='chore-info'>            
    <input type="checkbox" class="todoCheckbox">
        <p class='ID'>${choresArr[i].ID}</p>
        <input type='text' data-index='${choresArr[i].ID}' 
              class='chore' value='${choresArr[i].chore}'/>
        <p class='complete'>complete</p>
    </div>
    <div class='buttonCont'>
    <button id="${choresArr[i].ID}" class='remove-btn'>
        <i class="fa-solid fa-trash-can"></i>
        </button>
    </div>
    </li>`
```

```
function checkedBox() {
  const checkbox = document.querySelectorAll('input.todoCheckbox');
  const complete = document.querySelectorAll('p.complete')
  checkbox.forEach( (checkbox) => {
    checkbox.addEventListener('click', () => {
      const choresArr = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem('choresArr'));
      for ( let i = 0; i < choresArr.length; i += 1) {
        choresArr[i].checkbox == choresArr[i].complete;
               checkbox.checked == true;
        }
     // console.log(choresArr);
      localStorage.setItem('choresArr',
          JSON.stringify(choresArr));
    })
  });
}
```

Comment: Amalia, estás en [es.so]. El idioma oficial es el castellano. Por favor, traduce tu pregunta o terminará cerrada. Saludos

Comment: You may try to ask this question in the english version of StackOverflow, or you may translate it to fit Stack Overflow en Español guidelines

Comment: Puedes explicar que quieres hacer, no comprendi muy bien, es decir quieres que cuando se clickee el check, se guarde en true en el localstorage, pero en el local storage estas guardando un array o objeto? veo que lo pusiste pero no se como tengas esa estructura

Comment: Cuando hagas click en el checkbox('check') que cambie el input complete a valor true . Esta todo en local storage si. Aparte se van añadiendo varios elementos con checkboxes y por cada uno quiero que su respectivo complete cambie a true (verdadero) cuando se haga click. No se si me explico